# Subsetting with the diff() in R

Tags: r, diff, subset

I'm trying to create a subset of data from a data frame using the diff() and a logical condition.  So I have a bunch of data that can be represented like this:

```
time <- c(1,5,8,20,45,69,100,145,185,200)
code <- c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
df <- data.frame(time,code)
```

and then I want to subset it using this:

```
calib.data <- subset(df, diff(time) >= 15)
```

it all works great, expect that it throws away the last row, presumably bc there is nothing to subtract it from or subtract from it, whichever way it is doing the subtracting.

This would be simple to fix in excel.  You would just start the function on the second row and copy all the way to the last row, instead of starting in the first row and having the last row give you a hiccup.  In R, it is not this simple.  How can I get same result that I would get in excel example without the hiccup?  Basically everything is good, except that it throws out the last row, and I want to keep it.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Using your example, What is the expected output?  easy to add a TRUE or FALSE to `diff(time) >= 15` , for example `subset(df, c(diff(time) >= 15,TRUE))`

Comment: @agstudy - it's in the question - the same as `calib.data` but with the 10th row of `df` stuck on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cover off both the start and end of sequence possibilities with either:

```
# [ based subsetting
df[c(FALSE,diff(df$time) >= 15) | c(diff(df$time) >= 15,FALSE),]

# subset function
subset(df, c(FALSE,diff(time) >= 15) | c(diff(time) >= 15,FALSE))
```

Comment: that worked for almost all cases.  But when none of the differences meet the conditional statement, it throws them all out and subsets an empty set.  How can I ensure that the last row will always survive?